# How can I make a new order/transaction done through the API show on the Square app

Tags: square, square-connect

Online I allow customers to order, this causes an Order With Line Items to be uploaded and associated with a Transaction - that works great, exactly as I had hoped.  The problem is that there is no notification on the Square App to let my operators know that there is a new order that has been paid.

As of right now, I have the workaround of texting the workers, but I feel like there should be an easy way to push this up to the app - what am I missing?  Is this possible?

I am not using an online store, just the API.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, sending order confirmation to the Point of Sale app from an API payment isn’t currently available for Square’s API.

We are constantly improving the product based on feedback like this, so I’ll be sure to share your thoughts with the API team.

Comment: Could you please let me know if anything changes (same name on Square support forums)?  Thank you.